# Background-size:100% is slightly less than 100%

Tags: html, css

Please consider the following HTML and CSS :

**HTML**

```
<ul class="test1">
<li><div>Lorem ipsum</div></li>
<li><div>dolor sit amet</div></li>
</ul>
<ul class="test2">
    <li><div>Lorem ipsum</div>
    </li><li><div>dolor sit amet</div></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.test1 div {height:100px;}
.test2 div {height:200px;}
li 
{
    display: inline-block;
    width:100px;
    transition:background-position 0.2s ease;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, #F60 50%);
    background-size: 100% 200%;
    background-position : top left;
}
li:hover{color: #fff;background-position: bottom left;}
```

[cfr jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/facontrf/)

With a background being 200% of the height, and the top 50% of that background being transparent, that would mean that without hovering, all we can see is a transparent background. However, with this configuration I still can see a slight orange (`#F60`) line at the bottom, that being the bottom color of my "gradient" background.

If I want to fix this, I must specify background-size in pixels, and in that case I need to put background size as being (element size + 1 px)*2 . Could someone explain what causes this ? This is quite a problem as I would like to use this effect on blocks of a non-fixed height so percentage height is mandatory...

Comment: margins? padding? borders?

Comment: If you want to keep using percentages, setting the height to 201% eliminated the orange line.

Comment: nope, nope, nope ... what you're seeing is the narrowed down version I did input in jsfiddle and there's nothing more than this involved.

Comment: @dreamgt Yes I tried that but if the element is a bit higher than the 200px of my example, the bottom line is back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is a more involved answer that uses CSS animations: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/facontrf/7/)

Basically, I created colored `DIV` elements that have a 0% height. On hover of the parent `li` they grow to 100% height. The tricky part was preventing the return (shrink) animation from playing on page load: solved this by applying a white background to the overlaying text and fading it out after the initial page load completes (hideinit animation).

Added some classes and another DIV to the HTML markup:

```
<ul class="test1">
    <li><div class="text">Lorem ipsum</div><div class="orange"></div></li>
    <li><div class="text">dolor sit amet</div><div class="orange"></div></li>
</ul>
```

The updated CSS:
* *I left off the webkit vendor prefixed styles for brevity, they are included in the Fiddle*

```
li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    width:100px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
li:hover div.orange{
    animation: grow 1s 1 forwards;
}

li div.orange {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background: orange;
    height: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    animation: shrink 1s 1 forwards;
}
li div.text { 
    padding: 5px; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    animation: hideinit 1s 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes grow {
    from {height: 0%;}
    to {height: 100%;}
}
@keyframes shrink {
    from {height: 100%;}
    to {height: 0%;}
}
@keyframes hideinit {
    0% {background: white;}
    98% {background: white;}
    100% {background: none;}
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for this extensive answer ! Unfortunately I have some display glitches when I try this on Chrome (horizontal orange lines persisting in the middle of the element). I know these are related to display cause when I switch tabs and come back they have disappeared, so I may be the only one seeing it, but still I can't go on production knowing this... Too bad cause besides this Chrome glitch this solution works like a charm. (although I must admit I find it a lot of overhead for this simple effect but you can't do everything in a few lines...)

Comment: Sort of shows you that a javascript solution is probably less overhead (this feels almost hackish while a js solution would be quite simple and elegant).

Comment: Do me a favor and try this version: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/facontrf/11/). I took a slightly different approach: instead of resizing the orange boxes, I am simply sliding it vertically (and forcing it an extra 5% past the order of its parent container that has `overflow: hidden` set)

Comment: Unfortunately the same glitch is still there. Thank you for putting so much time into this answer, too bad :-/ [here's a screenshot of the glitch](http://hpics.li/7657586) so that you can see I'm not joking.

Comment: @Bartdude, okay last attempt (i have found a few references to some css-transitions issues in chrome [referemce](http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2014/02/fixing-css-transitions-in-google-chrome/)). the article suggests forcing chrome to use hardware acceleration with `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` -- here is the [**last ditch effort updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/facontrf/12/)

Comment: You'll be glad to know it works just fine now ! I validated your answer to reward you for the time and efforts you did put on this. I will most probably  try to rework it a bit in order to use pseudo-element instead of that extra div and if it is still OK I'll come here to post the fiddle. Thanks again mate !

Answer (score 1):

to remove the line at the bottom you are having add:

```
li{
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/facontrf/6/)

In response to dreamgt's comment I added some extra time to the animation. From:

```
transition:background-position 0.2s ease;
```

To:

```
transition:background-position 0.5s ease;
```

[New JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/facontrf/8/)

Comment: Although this seems to produce the result OP is looking for, it causes the css-transition animation to become jittery, and not as smooth.

Comment: adding more time to: transition:background-position 0.2s ease; seems to do the trick there.

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately it looks like the animation not only is a bit slower due the fix (not a big issue) but I also see some kind of extra delay before it starts, so theres a bigger amount of time when you don't see the text (white on white). Too bad cause that would have been my prefered answer regarding concision, so +1 for this anyway as this indeed answers the question...

Answer (score 1):

I know that other answers already suggested increasing the background-size height to 201%, and that you had issues with items larger than, lets say 300px, but I tried 202% and was able to increase the size of the div up to 900px with no orange line appearing.

So in summary:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    width:100px;
    transition:background-position 0.2s ease;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, #F60 50%);
    background-size: 100% 202%;
    background-position : top left;
}
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Although this is my least preferred answers because it's against (my) logic, it indeed answers my question in reasonable circumstances (this block will probably never be higher than 900px...), so I will validate it.

Comment: As JRulle found an answer working just fine I validated his answer but still gave you a +1 cause yours indeed does the job.

Answer (score 0):

increase the height by an additional 1%

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    width:100px;
    transition:background-position 0.2s ease;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%, #F60 50%);
    background-size: 100% 201%; /* <----------- increased height to 201% */
    background-position : top left;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/facontrf/2/)

Comment: Well, I tried that, but whenever the element is, let's say higher than 300px, the bottom line is back... I'm thinking maybe that's the "gradient" definition that should be updated, but I don't see what I could do more while still keeping percentage...